# Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark

Tags: unicode, awk, byte-order-mark

How would an `awk` script (presumably a one-liner) for removing a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) look like?

Specification:

- print every line after the first (`NR > 1`)
- for the first line: If it starts with `#FE #FF` or `#FF #FE`, remove those and print the rest

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==1{sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")}{print}' INFILE > OUTFILE
```

On the first record (line), remove the BOM characters. Print every record.

Or slightly shorter, using the knowledge that the default action in awk is to print the record:

```
awk 'NR==1{sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")}1' INFILE > OUTFILE
```

`1` is the shortest condition that always evaluates to true, so each record is printed.

Enjoy!

**-- ADDENDUM --**

[Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) includes the following table listing the exact BOM bytes for each encoding:

```
Bytes         |  Encoding Form
--------------------------------------
00 00 FE FF   |  UTF-32, big-endian
FF FE 00 00   |  UTF-32, little-endian
FE FF         |  UTF-16, big-endian
FF FE         |  UTF-16, little-endian
EF BB BF      |  UTF-8
```

Thus, you can see how `\xef\xbb\xbf` corresponds to `EF BB BF` `UTF-8` BOM bytes from the above table.

Comment: It seems that the dot in the middle of the sub statement is too much (at least, my awk complains about it). Beside this it's exactly what I searched, thanks!

Comment: This solution, however, works **only** for UTF-8 encoded files. For others, like UTF-16, see Wikipedia for the corresponding BOM representation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: I agree with the earlier comment; the dot does not belong in the middle of this statement and makes this otherwise great little snippet an example of an awk syntax error.

Comment: So: `awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"");print}' INFILE > OUTFILE` and make sure INFILE and OUTFILE are different!

Comment: If you used `perl -i.orig -pe 's/^\x{FFFE}//' badfile` you could rely on your PERL_UNICODE and/or PERLIO envariables for the encoding.  PERL_UNICODE=SD would work for UTF-8; for the others, you’d need PERLIO.

Comment: Maybe a little bit shorter version: `awk 'NR==1{sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")}1'`

Comment: Works great on OS X El Capitan `10.11.6`.

Comment: /!\ Both commands erased my file, as a "side-effect" of changing the encoding... Quite fortunate to have had them backed up first.

Comment: If you're trying to just change the file (not create a new one) and for some reason can't use sed (as per the answer below), make sure to use `-i inplace` and not put the input file as the output file, which will erase the file!

Answer (score 127):

Using GNU `sed` (on Linux or Cygwin):

```
# Removing BOM from all text files in current directory:
sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.txt
```

On FreeBSD:

```
sed -i .bak '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.txt
```

Advantage of using GNU or FreeBSD `sed`: the `-i` parameter means "in place", and will update files without the need for redirections or weird tricks.

On Mac:

[This `awk` solution in another answer works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068700/1148030), but the `sed` command above does not work. At least on Mac (Sierra) `sed` documentation does not mention supporting hexadecimal escaping ala `\xef`.

A similar trick can be achieved with any program by piping to the `sponge` tool from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
awk '…' INFILE | sponge INFILE
```

Comment: I tried the second command precisely on Mac OS X and the result was "success", but the substitution didn't actually occur.

Comment: It is worth noting these commands replace one specific byte sequence, which is [one of the possible byte-order-marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding). Maybe your file had a different BOM sequence. (I can't help other than that, as I don't have a Mac)

Comment: When I tried the second command on OS X on a file that used 0xef 0xbb 0xbf as the BOM, it did not actually do the substitution.

Comment: In OSX, I could only get this to work via perl, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9101056/2063546

Comment: On OS X El Capitan `10.11.6`, this doesn't work, but the official answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1068700/9636 works fine.

Answer (score 42):

Not awk, but simpler:

```
tail -c +4 UTF8 > UTF8.nobom
```

To check for BOM:

```
hd -n 3 UTF8
```

If BOM is present you'll see: `00000000  ef bb bf ...`

Comment: BOMs are  2 bytes for UTF-16 and 4 bytes for UTF-32, and of course have no business being in UTF-8 in the first place.

Comment: @tchrist: from wikipedia: "The Unicode Standard does permit the BOM in UTF-8, but does not require or recommend its use. Byte order has no meaning in UTF-8 so in UTF-8 the BOM serves only to **identify** a text stream or file as UTF-8."

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, precisely. Its use is not recommended. It breaks stuff. The encoding should be specified by a higher-level protocol.

Comment: @tchrist: you mean it breaks broken stuff? :) proper apps should be able to handle that BOM.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I mean it *breaks **lots** of programs*. Isn’t that what I said? When you open a stream in the UTF-16 or UTF-32 encodings, the decoder knows not to count the BOM. When you use UTF-8, decoders present the BOM as data. This is a syntax error in innumerable programs. [Even Java’s decoder behaves this way, BY DESIGN!](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058) BOMs on UTF-8 files are misplaced and a pain in the butt: **they are an error!** They break many things. Even just `cat file1.utf8 file2.utf8 file3.utf3 > allfiles.utf8` will be broken. Never use a BOM on UTF-8. Period.

Comment: @@tchrist:: that's what you said... and I said something else. BTW Java's decoder isn't broken by *design*. it's a *bug* and they kept it for backward compatibility.

Comment: `hd` is not available on OS X (as of 10.8.2), so to check for an UTF-8 BOM there you can use the following: `head -c 3 file | od -t x1`.

Comment: `if [[ "`file a.txt | grep -o 'with BOM'`" == "BOM" ]];` can also be used

Comment: `hexdump` and `xdd` should work in place of `hd`, if that's not available on your system.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to converting CRLF line endings to LF, `dos2unix` also removes BOMs:

```
dos2unix *.txt
```

`dos2unix` also converts UTF-16 files with a BOM (but not UTF-16 files without a BOM) to UTF-8 without a BOM:

```
$ printf '\ufeffä\n'|iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16be>bom-utf16be
$ printf '\ufeffä\n'|iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le>bom-utf16le
$ printf '\ufeffä\n'>bom-utf8
$ printf 'ä\n'|iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16be>utf16be
$ printf 'ä\n'|iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le>utf16le
$ printf 'ä\n'>utf8
$ for f in *;do printf '%11s %s\n' $f $(xxd -p $f);done
bom-utf16be feff00e4000a
bom-utf16le fffee4000a00
   bom-utf8 efbbbfc3a40a
    utf16be 00e4000a
    utf16le e4000a00
       utf8 c3a40a
$ dos2unix -q *
$ for f in *;do printf '%11s %s\n' $f $(xxd -p $f);done
bom-utf16be c3a40a
bom-utf16le c3a40a
   bom-utf8 c3a40a
    utf16be 00e4000a
    utf16le e4000a00
       utf8 c3a40a
```

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was directed at unix/linux, thought it would be worth to mention a good option for the unix-challenged (on windows, with a UI).

I ran into the same issue on a WordPress project (BOM was causing problems with rss feed and page validation) and I had to look into all the files in a quite big directory tree to find the one that was with BOM. Found an application called [Replace Pioneer](http://www.mind-pioneer.com/) and in it:

Batch Runner -> Search (to find all the files in the subfolders) -> Replace Template ->  Binary remove BOM (there is a ready made search and replace template for this).

It was not the most elegant solution and it did require installing a program, which is a downside. But once I found out what was going around me, it worked like a charm (and found 3 files out of about 2300 that were with BOM).

Comment: I am so happy when I found your solution, however I don't have the privilege to install software on company computer. Took lots of time today, until I figure out the alternative: Using Notepad++ with PythonScript plugin .  http://superuser.com/questions/418515/how-to-find-all-files-in-directory-that-contain-utf-8-bom-byte-order-mark/914116#914116 Thanks anyway!