# Weird Issue Causing Header to be dropped down on only 1 page

Tags: html, css, server-side-includes

Check out http://cancerpreventionnetwork.org/participants.shtml and you can see that the header is dropped down on this page. If you click on any other page, the header is not dropped like that. I have tried everything and I can't figure out what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check the page in Chrome with *inspect element*, I see an extra `text node`.  I can't see it in the source, but maybe you can?

[image]

Comment: I saw that too, but I can't figure out where it's coming from. If you check the `GET participants.shtml` response in the net panel in firebug I don't even see it there.

Comment: It could be some space in one of your `includes`.  See if you can delete any extra spacing before or after the code in the `includes`

Comment: @Catfish The text nodes are inserted because you have the Divs on a newline.  Try putting your `<body id="membership"><div id="container"><div id="banner">..` on the same line without spaces.  When I get rid of the text node, it displays properly.  It's strange, though, because you have the same format on the other pages and it's working there.

Comment: Seemed to be a hidden character that I couldn't see using gedit in linux, but I could see it using ned in linux.

Answer (score 1):

seems to me that it's the classic UTF8 BOM encoding problem

you need to check all your source files and make sure that they are not encoded using the BOM.

there are many ways to remove it. I use notepad++ but there might be an automated tool or some shell code to remove the BOM for multiple files

and also.. if you're including files (templates) make sure that they don't have white spaces or new lines after the `?>`

Good Luck

Comment: I just looked at the page using firebug and I didn't see anything that says BOM. Where do you see that?

Comment: there's no easy way to do that =P but check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark