# UTF-8 no BOM gets strange random characters around site

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I'm saving my files with UTF-8 with no BOM to get around "headers already sent" issue. However I get strange characters in the whole site, I don't know why since saving files the same in other sites don't cause the same issue.

I get this: `ï»¿` a lot of times in random spots of my site and some special characters are displayed incorrectly.

http://chusmix.com/?ciudad=Pilar

How can I fix this?

Comment: That does look like a BOM. Double check that all your files, including files you `include`, are saved as NO-BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ï»¿` is the BOM so it probably hasn't been removed properly. To completely remove it, you could batch process all your files - check if the first characters match the BOM and if so, remove it. There are plenty of scripts on the internet to do that. For example: [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)

Comment: I discovered some files weren't encoding with UTF-8 no BOM. I don't know why, I save them with no BOM but when I reopen them they are back in ANSI.