# Remove multiple BOMs from a file

Tags: unicode, byte-order-mark

I am using a Javascript file that is a concatenation of other JavaScript files.

Unfortunately, the person who concatenated these JavaScript files together did not use the proper encoding when reading the file, and allowed a BOM for every single JavaScript file to get written to the concatenated JavaScript file.

Does anyone know a simple way to search through the concatenated file and remove any/all BOM markers?

Using PHP or a bash script for Mac OSX would be great.

Comment: have you tryed using Notepad++, Encodage > select the one that should be there, Convert it back to UTF8-NoBoms

Comment: What is a compiled Javascript file? You surely mean concatenated or what?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See also: [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)

To remove multiple BOMs from anywhere within a text file you can try something similar. Just leave out the `^` anchor:

```
perl -e 's/\xef\xbb\xbf//;' -pi~ file.js
```

(This edits the file in-place. But creates a backup `file.js~`.)

Answer (score 18):

I normally do it using `vim`:

```
vim -c "set nobomb" -c wq! myfile
```

Comment: This worked for me. I just couldn't get the `sed` command to strip them.

Answer (score 1):

fetch BOM files

`grep -rIlo $’^\xEF\xBB\xBF’ ./`

remove BOM files

`grep -rIlo $’^\xEF\xBB\xBF’ . | xargs sed –in-place -e ‘s/\xef\xbb\xbf//’`

exclude .svn dir

`grep -rIlo –exclude-dir=”.svn” $’^\xEF\xBB\xBF’ . | xargs sed –in-place -e ‘s/\xef\xbb\xbf//’`

- See more at: http://www.a5go.com/how-to-remove-bom-from-utf-8-using-sed.html#

Answer (score 0):

I also figured out this solution which works entirely in PHP:

```php
$packed = pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf);
$contents = preg_replace('/'.$packed.'/','',$contents);
```

Comment: It's probably easier to type `"\xef\xbb\xbf"`, see [double quoted string escapes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a bash script see [here](https://github.com/LudvigWesterdahl/Scripts/blob/master/rmbom) that works for Mac, I haven't tested on other systems but I suspect it should work there as well. The script also support files or file paths that contains spaces.

**Examples**

Remove BOM from all files in current directory:

`rmbom .`

Print all files with a BOM in the current directory

`rmbom . -a`

Only remove BOM from all files in current directory with extension txt or cs:

`rmbom . -e txt -e cs`

Print help

`rmbom -h`