# Error occurs when I build the code with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I compile the project successfully in Eclipse without any error.

But when I tried to compile it in IntelliJ, the following error shows:

[image]

I double-clicked the error message, it located into the first line of one Java class, which is the package definition line, and there's no compilation error in this class.

I tried to fix this by specifying the JDK, but it didn't work.

Anyone knows what's happening here?

Comment: sounds like a BOM issue in the java source file. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100728/remove-multiple-boms-from-a-file for solutions to remove it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saved my file with UTF-8 encoding without DOM in Sublime, then it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks RC. I saved my file with UTF-8 in Sublime, then it works.

This is what I did:
Open the file with Sublime, `File->Save with Encoding`, there will be `UTF-8` and `UTF-8 with DOM`, select the first one, then it compiled successfully in IntelliJ.