# Why the command used to remove BOM doesn't work?

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I found a command to **find documents in my all-level folders and directories that are utf-8 with BOM and then remove the BOM**. But it doesn't seem to work on my computer(osx)...Should I install moodle on my machine first in order to run it in my command line?

Below is the command:

`find . -type f -exec sed 's/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' -i.bak {} \; -exec rm {}.bak \;`

The result I got is `sed: -i.bak: No such file or directory` and all the content in the files, which seems very weird.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the result?

Comment: Just updated the question. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The command you found was for GNU's sed, which supports optional arguments anywhere. Worst of all, OS X's sed doesn't seem to support non-ASCII byte sequences.

Instead, for OS X use the following answer, which uses Perl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101056/1554386

Tying it into find is as follows:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -e 's/\xef\xbb\xbf//;' -pi.bak {} \;
```

You can add the `-exec rm {}.bak \;` from your command if you wish, but you can just as easily do that separately

Comment: Thank you Alastair. That helps a lot! I'll use it in the future! :)

Comment: Np. BTW, make sure you upvote and accept questions if they work for you. People are more likely to respond if they think you'll reward them for answering.

Comment: Oops, I thought I already voted you up. So just voted. Thank you again!

Comment: No worries - also see this about accepting answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Basically, you get extra reputation for accepting