# Failure trying to verify CSR with Openssl

Tags: openssl

I have a CSR (X509 certificate signing request) that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
13 lines of <base 64>: 12 lines of 64 characters, 
followed by 1 line of 52 characters
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I was told that to verify the CSR, I could use this command:

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in my.csr
```

but when I run that, I get this error:

```
unable to load X509 request
4419198400:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
```

I get the same error if I use `openssl req -in my.csr -noout -text` (leaving out the `verify`)

If I paste the contents of the file into an online tool (website), the tools I have tried seem to parse it OK, but I would like to be able to do this locally, so I get all the information (the online tools do not tell me everything that is in the CSR). Can someone please tell me how to make this work?

Comment: I tested this, and it works for me.  Was the CSR created by the same version of `openssl` that you are using to try to parse the CSR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the command is correct, and the file looks correct when printed or the text copied and pasted, but apparently the file came from a Windows system and starts with a BOM (Byte Order Mark), and `openssl` does not like the BOM at the beginning of the line. The problem is shown by the `file` command output including "(with BOM)"

```
$ file my.csr 
my.csr: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Once I edited the file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14714484/2349402) to remove the BOM

```
vim -c "set nobomb" -c wq my.csr
```

then the command in the post worked.