# Can't import less files encoded in UTF-8 BOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, less

I use the less compiler with node.js and I know there is an issue with the files encoded in UTF-8 with BOM. For this, this workaround works great:

```
data = data.replace(/^\uFEFF/, ''); // Strip potential BOM
```

However, when importing files, using `@import` statements still gives a syntax error on first line. Are there any way to work around this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BOM will be stripped in the next version of less.js - 1.3.1. You can also try it out on the github source pages.

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/commit/6696368eb351824f33dc0aac67143d8ea80a085a

Answer (score 0):

A [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in an UTF-8 file makes no sense.

You should fix the source files as many other tools will (rightly) have problems with this BOM. All serious editors are able to write UTF-8 files without BOM.

If you must receive and handle such files, you should automaticaly fix them using for example (operating on a work copy if needed) :

```
awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"");print}' INFILE > OUTFILE
```

(taken from [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark))

Comment: I won't control all the input files here, so I can't base the solution on the editor used, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can't you make (automatically) a copy of those files and fix them before they enter your build chain ?

Comment: I guess it's a solution, but I guess I'm better off waiting for a new release or try to change the source code :)