# I get syntax error when I execute this python scripts but not when I invoke the interpreter

Tags: python

in a file called test.py I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

with open('test.txt','w') as File:
    print(1,file=File)
```

When I do

```
$ python3 test.py
```

It runs fine. But when I do

```
$ chmod +x test.py
$ ./test.py
```

I get a SyntaxError:

```
  File "./test.py", line 4
    print(1,file=File)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any one has any idea why? Thank you

I'm running Python 3.3.1 in Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: What does `which python3` tell you is the path?

Comment: The syntax error is thrown by Python 2.x; `/usr/bin/python3` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `which python` is `/usr/bin/python3` which is python 3.3.1 (if I run `/usr/bin/python3` I get the Python 3.3.1 interpreter. More so, If I do `/usr/bin/python3 test.py` it all works nice)

Comment: @PatricioClark Very strange. What happens if you change the script to do: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`? Edit: might also be worth adding `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: Is it possible that `test.py` isn't what you think it is? A file open in the wrong editor for example?

Comment: @Aya Oh, it prints `/usr/bin/python`, which is Python 2.7. So the thing is, why isn't it respecting the shabang?

Comment: @BrendanLong No, I actually had the problem in another (and bigger) script. I created this example specifically to isolate it.

Comment: Maybe there's whitespace at the beginning of the file?

Comment: But you do run this exact script and have the same problem, right?

Comment: @PatricioClark I've tried running the same script on Ubuntu 12.10, and I can't reproduce the problem. Try `xxd test.py` and check the first two bytes are 0x23 0x21.

Comment: @BrendanLong of test.py? The first character of the first line of the file is the # from the shabang.

Comment: Maybe the file starts with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which your editor would probably hide. You could change the encoding in your editor to ASCII when you save, or use one of the methods [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) to remove it.

Comment: @Aya the first line of the `xxd test.py` output is  `0000000: 2321 2f75 7372 2f62 696e 2f65 6e76 2070  #!/usr/bin/env p` So the first two bytes are correct?

Comment: @PatricioClark ...and the second line?

Comment: @Aya The second line `0000010: 7974 686f 6e33 0a0a 7769 7468 206f 7065  ython3..with ope`

Comment: @PatricioClark Okay. There's nothing wrong with that, so it must be something with the shell you're using. Does it work if you do `bash -c "./test.py"`?

Comment: @BrendanLong I checked and no BOM at the beginning of the file

Comment: @Aya Thank you! I was using a zsh suffix alias that run python on *.py files. After removing that suffix alias everything is working perfectly. Big thank you to all of you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a Python 2 interpreter for some reason. Maybe trying using [`env`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) to search for the correct `python3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('test.txt','w') as File:
    print(1,file=File)
```

`env` should find the same `python3` that your shell does.

It's worth mentioning that this is a good idea even if you're not having problems, since it makes your scripts more portable by letting them run on any platform where `python3` is available, no matter where it is.