# How to remove special character Â character in a file in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, byte-order-mark

Below is the data in my file:

```
one_1.10=to - Standard (Â£1.10)
ITV_1.10=to - Standard (Â£1.10)
```

I want to remove Â in my file in unix?

i tried below methods. Opened the file in vi mode  and gave below commands

```
:set nobomb
:wq

sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' <fileName>
```

But the BOM character is not getting removed. Could someone please help?

Comment: Does `sed -i 's/Â//g' file` work to you?

Comment: What you're trying to remove is definitely not a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Hi  fedorqui. Its not working. its showing like pattern not found, though the pattern is there.

Comment: Hi devnull. I thought its a BOM charac.. Anyway i m just trying to remove that character.

Comment: I found another way to replace all non-ascii characters in all files inside the current directory :

find . -type f | xargs perl -pi.bak -e 's,[^[:ascii:]],,g'

afterwards you will have to find and remove all the '.bak' files:

find . -type f -a -name \*.bak | xargs rm

but this is also replacing £ with empty string. does anyone has any idea like how to exclude £ by using above commands?

Comment: Fyi: original title was "How to remove BOM character Â character in a file in unix?", but that's not what this question is about. If that's what you're looking for, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark

Comment: It's not clear what is in the file. Consider sharing hexdump of the data file (hexdump -n32 -c, or similar)

Comment: You don't want to "remove" anything; you want to stop interpretering your UTF-8-encoded file as an ISO-8859-encoded file. The UTF-8 encoding of U+00A3 just happens to contain the byte `\xA3` as well, so `£` is being displayed as `Â£`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a UTF-8-encoded file. The UTF-8 encoding of U+00A3 (£) is `\xc2\xa3`. When you view your file, however, you are assuming it is using a different encoding, like ISO-8859. As a result, the two-byte sequence `\xc2\xa3` is not decoded as U+00A3, but as two separate characters U+00C2 (Â) and UU+00A3 (£). (ISO 8859, being a subset of Unicode, shares its code points with Unicode, but as a single-byte encoding, does *not* correspond to UTF-8.)

So you don't want to edit the file at all, except maybe to *convert* the encoding from UTF-8 to some there single-byte encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat <filename> | sed 's/\xc2//g'
```

You had the right idea, but the wrong character (based on your example).

Comment: I don't think the text you are trying to work with is getting represented properly above. When I paste your example text into a file on my system, the 'Â' looks like a 0xC2 character when viewed in a hex editor. Try viewing your original file in hex and replace the \xc2 with whatever character it really is. For viewing hex: emacs can do this (open the file then press Esc., x, type hexl-mode and press enter). Or run 'od -h <filename>'.