# something wrong when I exec a script with perl (ubuntu10.10)

Tags: perl, bash, ubuntu

I got a perl script named test_perl.pl and try to exec it.
The first line of the scrpit is:

```
﻿#!/usr/bin/perl
```

When I try to exec this script, I get an error.

```
$ type perl
perl is /usr/bin/perl

$ ll /usr/bin/perl test_perl.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root        root        10352 2011-04-23 03:32 /usr/bin/perl*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim         jim         12121 2013-11-21 11:47 test_perl.pl*


$ test_perl.pl
test_perl.pl: line 1: ﻿#!/usr/bin/perl: No such file or directory
```

I don't no why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a BOM (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your file.

try

```
 xxd test_perl.pl
```

to see it. Getting rid of the BOM will fix your script: Lots of ways to do this: [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark)