# Grunt NameError: variable @gutter is undefined

Tags: wordpress, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I am using [Shoestrap](http://shoestrap.org/), a WordPress theme based on Roots that uses Bootstrap and less. I added the Bootswatch [Yeti theme](http://bootswatch.com/yeti/) variables.less to assets/less/bootstrap as as a replacement of the existing one and also added bootswatch.less. Then I added bootswatch.less to bootstrap.less. To recompile I ran `grunt`.  The grunt file content I have added [here](http://pastebin.com/7dapFEAc).
I ran into two issues though. One error I do not know how to fix and one major issue that is that grunt seems to keep on removing assets/css/main.min.css all the time and then tells me the file or directory is missing. Here are the errors I had with `--force` activated:

```
grunt --force
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task
>> NameError: variable @gutter is undefined in assets/less/app.less on line 5, column 13:
>> 4 .gallery-row {
>> 5   padding: (@gutter / 2) 0;
>> 6 }
Warning: Error compiling assets/less/app.less Used --force, continuing.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
File "assets/js/scripts.min.js" created.

Running "version" task
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'assets/css/main.min.css' Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

It was the Byte Order Mark ([BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) signature that was an issue as I linked to before in the question. But both TextWrangler and Dreamweaver did not remove it. I found one command that did help here: [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) And I ran

```
awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"");print}' app.less > app.less
```

which worked like a charm! Only the theme still has not changed in styling. That is rather odd.

**Update I**

The awk command emptied my app.less. I ran another command found here as well: [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) and that command:

```
sed -i .bak '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.less
```

did work without removing all data from app.less, but then I got the same error again:

```
Reading assets/less/app.less...OK
>> NameError: variable @gutter is undefined in assets/less/app.less on line 5, column 13:
>> 4 .gallery-row {
>> 5   padding: (@gutter / 2) 0;
>> 6 }
```

Did see TextMate added attributes and removed those using `xattr -d com.macromates.caret file.less`, but that did not do the trick either.

**Update II**

Seems that the variable `@gutter` does not exist. There seems to be a variable `@grid-gutter-width`. Thanks to at Roots Discourse I was notified - http://discourse.roots.io/t/grunt-hits-a-snag-compiling-gutter-not-defined/940/3 . Making an adjustment does not help though as other variables pop-up as issues. Will see if I can get some feedback from the Shoestrap team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the shoestrap, theme, I believe we managed to fix it with this commit: https://github.com/shoestrap/shoestrap/commit/ff75cf73cf778e4b80c5e11544c0a67717fbcc10

Please let me know if that works for you...