# Can't remove first two encode characters using text editors in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, encode

When I use text editor for seeing content of file `a.csv` it shows me:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk
```

But when I `cat` it I have:

```
��aaa   bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk
```

So when I want to remove first to characters `��` I can't do that. For example:

```
cat a.csv | sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)//'
```

The result is:

```
��aa    bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1068650/1679537

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a byte order mark that's prepended to your text.

If that is correct, you can fix this by converting your file to an encoding that doesn't use a byte order mark (for example plain UTF-8), and these two characters should be gone.

How you change the encoding of a file depends on the editor you use, in `vim` the command to use is `:set nobomb`.

Comment: Thank you,,,How is it possible?

Comment: The BOM is three bytes in UTF-8, though; but perhaps the terminal is not displaying every byte as an unknown character. +1 -- this would be my first speculation, too.

Comment: I didn't get it... pardon

Comment: @MortezaLSC How you change the encoding depends on your editior. Some have the option in the `Save as...` dialog, some have a special menu entry for this, some allow you to change the encoding via a pop-up or context menu. Quite a few editors don't even have the option.

Comment: I am using `vim` to see the content of a.csv...These  are lots of file..I want to use bash for dealing with such issues

Comment: @tripleee There are byte order marks with two, three, four, and even five bytes, see this link for a complete list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

Comment: In `vim` you can just do `:set nobomb` before writing the file to remove a byte order mark (no idea why they called the option `bomb`...).

Comment: It is of course possible that there are invisible zero bytes but the available information suggests an 8-bit encoding on the OP's terminal and in the file.

Comment: @cmaster Thank you, +1...good solution... If I want to do it for more than 1000 files. Do we have a rational(automated\) way?

Comment: Yes, you have two options for this: 1. use vim's `argdo` command, 2. use the shell to iterate over the files and call `vim $file '+set nobomb' +w +q` in the loop. The first will likely be faster, and it won't flash your terminal screen as the second one will. Nevertheless, the `+` trick is quite useful to know.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @IlijaDimov Rephrased my answer a bit, hope you like it better now.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(\o357\o277\o275){2}//g' file
```

this removes any double occurance of the octal triple `\357\277\275`.

N.B. to recognize the octal value use `sed -n l file` and scan for values begining `\nnn`

Comment: It doesn't work for me .... :(

Comment: Why do you expect and require two occurrences of this sequence?