# line 1: ?#!/usr/bin/sh: not found when trying to execute a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script called **autoinstall**:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Installasi membutuhkan free space minimal 2MB, pastikan ada punya cukup space di router anda"
read -p "Anda yakin ingin melanjutkan installasi?(y/n) " -n 1 -r
echo ""
if [[ $REPLY = ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    cd /
    cd /tmp/
    tar -xvf OpenWrt_Angel_Beats_Edition_v1.3.3.tar -C /
    chmod -R 744 /root/crt
    chmod 744 /www/wget/wget_download.sh
    chmod 744 /usr/bin/gsm
    chmod 744 /usr/bin/profile
    opkg update && opkg install elinks
    cp /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.local.backup
    cat > /etc/rc.local << END
    #!bin/sh
    # /etc/rc.local: Local system initialization script.
    #
    # Put any local startup commands in here. Also, if you have
    # anything that needs to be run at shutdown time you can
    # make an /etc/rc.d/rc.local_shutdown script and put those
    # commands in there.
    sh /www/wget/wget_download.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    exit 0
END
    killall sh /www/wget/wget_download.sh
    sh /www/wget/wget_download.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo "File backup /etc/rc.local.backup telah dibuat, gunakan file ini untuk mengembalikan konfigurasi rc.local anda yang dulu jika diperlukan"
    echo "Installasi selesai. Jangan lupa di akun openvpn yang digunakan (/root/crt/xxx.ovpn) tambahkan baris ini:
    script-security 2
    up client-connect.sh"
else
    echo ""
    echo "Installasi dibatalkan"
fi
```

Every command that I put in the first line always gets the error above (`line 1:xxx not found`) and I'm sure I've typed in the correct command, even `echo` gives the error like that, how do I solve this?

Comment: Have you run `/usr/bin/sh` for test?

Comment: yes, but that's not the case, every command that I put in the first line gets error like that, I don't know what went wrong

Comment: What are you using to edit the scripts? A Windows machine? Could this be a `BOM` issue? What does `file <script>` say?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ on windows 7 and I run that on my router with OpenWrt installed in it. What do you mean by `file <script>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file might have been edited with an editor that insert a Unicode BOM (Byte Order Mark).

Have a look to the first line contents with:

```
od -c autoinstall | head -1
```

or

```
hd -n 16 autoinstall
```

If you see unexpected characters before `#!/usr/bin/sh`, you might try one of the methods described here [Using awk to remove the Byte-order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) to remove the BOM.

Comment: Thanks, solved by going to notepad++ -> Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 Without BOM and then save my file again, thank you!

Comment: Same here. Cleared that BOM and the message went away.

Answer (score 6):

There can be two problems here:

1. The file doesn't exist. Usually, for `sh`, the path is `/bin/sh`, so it should be `#!/bin/sh`
2. You're editing the file on Windows. Windows uses CR+LF as line ending. Unix (and Linux) uses just LF. So for Linux, the command reads "execute `/bin/sh<CR>` and `sh<CR>` doesn't exist.

Solution: When editing the file, make sure you use Unix line endings.