# change encoding for all files in VS Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've got a large solution for ASP.NET MVC Web application. Some source files in projects inside this solution are using win1251 encoding and other files use UTF-8. Is there any way to quickly convert all files to UTF-8?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9802561/84507