# How to get rid of invisible characters after converting

Tags: unix, ksh

I want to convert windows UTF8 file containing a special apostrophe to unix ISO-8859-1 file. This is how I am doing it :

```
# -- unix file
tr -d '\015' < my_utf8_file.xml > t_my_utf8_file.xml

# -- get rid of special apostrophe
sed "s/’/'/g" t_my_utf8_file.xml > temp_my_utf8_file.xml

#  -- change the xml header
sed "s/UTF-8/ISO-8859-1/g" temp_my_utf8_file.xml > my_utf8_file_temp.xml

# -- the actual charecter set conversion
iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1 my_utf8_file_temp.xml > my_file.xml
```

Everything is fine but one thing in one of my files. It seems like there is originally an invisible character at the beginning of the file. When I open my_file.xml in Notepadd ++, I see a SUB at the beginning of the file. In Unix VI I see ^Z.

What and where should I add to my unix script to delete those kinds of characters.

Thank you

Comment: When your only problem is the first char, you can `sed '1 s/.//'`.

Comment: @mlwacosmos, You are seeing the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). There are multiple ways to remove it, many are addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out exactly what character(s) you're dealing with, isolate the line in question (in this case something simple like `head -1 <file>` should suffice) and pipe the result to `od` (using the appropriate flag to display the character(s) in the desired format):

```
head -1 <file> | od -c   # view as character
head -1 <file> | od -d   # view as decimal
head -1 <file> | od -o   # view as octal
head -1 <file> | od -x   # view as hex
```

Once you know the character(s) you're dealing with you can use your favorite command (eg, `tr`, `sed`) to remove said character.

Comment: Using head -1 <file> | od -c, the invisible character is : 357 273 277

Comment: you're already using `tr` to remove a character, so add these characters to that `tr` command; alternatively, do something like: `sed 's/\x<hex#1>\x<hex#2>\x<hex#3//g'` where you replace `<hex#N>` with the hex codes output by `od -x`.: